# Understanding a step in this proof

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I have it tagged as representation theory because it's out of my rep theory book but I'm really just misunderstanding a group theory aspect here.

So the statement to prove is: if $G$ has odd order then $G$ has no nontrivial real representation.

And here's how the solution starts: Assume $x\in G$ is real, so $x$ is conjugate to $x^{-1}$, or $g^{-1}xg=x^{-1}$ for some $g\in G$. Then $g^{-2}xg^{2}=x$, so $g^2\in C_G(x)$.

This is the step I don't understand. How did he get $g^{-2}xg^{2}=x$? I feel like I'm probably missing something really obvious, but I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$g^{-2}xg^2=g^{-1}(g^{-1}xg)g=g^{-1}x^{-1}g=(g^{-1}xg)^{-1}=(x^{-1})^{-1}=x$$